# Serialize nullable enum wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, enums, xsd

I 've problem with serialize my enum to nullable enum. I would like to make enum as a nullable with minoccurs = 0.

Here's my enum:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    val_1= 0,
    val_2 = 1,
    val_3 = 2,
    val_4 = 3
}
```

I've tried serialize as a string or with "spefified" flag but it's use only for boolean values.

So finally I want to get xsd like this:

```
<element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TestEnum" type="TestEnum"/>
```

I always get minOccurs="1"

Comment: And what is the problem? Other than "I have a problem".

Comment: Check my updated post.

Comment: this is en enum definition, an enum is never null but the property with that type can be declared as nullable. (classic example is something as public int? Value{get; set;})  How had you declared property?

Comment: @Othello.netdev I've also tried thi way, but then I got nillable=true, but not minOccurs=0

Comment: I think than "nillable=true" is a good starting point, it let you define a value or nothing. Why you need "minOccurs=0" ? How do you "get xsd" ?

Comment: It's required from my other side. XSD is generated from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't love this solution but i've found a workaround

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Val1,
    Val2,
}

public class TestDefine
{
    public string MyEnumPropSerialize
    {
        get
        {
            if (MyEnumProp.HasValue)
            {
                return MyEnumProp.ToString();
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            MyEnum importValue;
            if (Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(value, out importValue))
            {
                MyEnumProp = importValue;
            }else
            {
                MyEnumProp.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public MyEnum? MyEnumProp { get; set; }
}
```

this class, when you execute xsd.exe create this xsd definition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="TestDefine" nillable="true" type="TestDefine" />
  <xs:complexType name="TestDefine">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MyEnumPropSerialize" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

It's correct XSD but i've inserted one property "fake" to force XSD generator to create XSD as you want.

I think than if XSD.exe generator don't meet your requirements you need to customize itself or create XSD manually. After that you can implement IXmlSerializer method on your object so you'll get full control on deserialization and XML parsing